# CloudKit: Proper Security Role for Web Services App

Tags: cloudkit, cloudkit-web-services

I have a server-side application that uses CloudKit Web Services to make changes to my CloudKit container. I generated a server-to-server key for this.

I want my server-side script to be able to update any record of type `Person` in my Public Database, but I'm getting an error:

> [reason] => WRITE operation not permitted
>
> [serverErrorCode] => ACCESS_DENIED

The options for the security roles for my `Person` record are as follows:

[image: CloudKit Security Roles]

If I check **Write** then it works and I don't get the error anymore.

But I'm concerned that I just gave all users of my app access to make changes to any record in that table. Is there a way to **only** allow write access to my application and its server-to-server key?

Answer (score 0):

It's sad at how quiet the CloudKit community is on SO. Perhaps that's because the only people that really know how CloudKit works work at Apple. ;)

I saw in a [2016 WWDC talk](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2016/226) that server-to-server requests happen as an "admin" user, so I'm guessing that it's safe to check the **Write** option for this record type.